# Wifi issues after latest update to 21.04

Tags: wireless, ping, gateway

I have an issue with 21.04 in that I cannot ping the gateway although netstat  -nr shows the right config and this was after I upgraded last time.

I can see a valid IP address for wlo0 and when I boot form the install usb stick I can get internet.

Help please.
John

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Last update to 21.04??? I'd check your details; as Ubuntu 21.04 reached EOL back in January, meaning https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release was altered to reflect "*Supported = 0*" at that time, so upgrades for it, or updates to it have not been possible for some time. Are you using Ubuntu 21.04? or something else?